# Find a second solution of the given differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
xy''+y'=0; y_1=ln(x)
$$

I solved this all the way to the end and found my second solution to be $y_2=-1$, but the book says it is $y_2=1$. I am checking my algebra and the method I used was to get it to $u''+u'(\frac{2+ln(x)}{xln(x)})=0$. I then made the substitution $w=u'$. Is this correct? I feel as though I was supposed to use $w=u'(\frac{2+ln(x)}{xln(x)})$ but I'm not sure. Is there a faster way to do this problem?

Comment: isn' t $y = 1$ another solution?

Comment: Did you find that by inspection? 

In the chapter we are on in my class we are offered to methods: set $y=u(x)y_1$ or just use $y_2=y_1(x)\int\frac{e^{-\int P(x)dx}}{y_1^2(x)}dx$

Comment: Since this is a linear homogeneous equation, you can multiply a solution by any nonzero constant and get another solution.  You're free to write the second solution as $1$ or $-1$ or $2015$; all are equally correct.

Comment: The fastest way is to notice that only derivatives of $y$ appear in the equation, not $y$ itself, so it's obvious that constants are solutions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael in regards to your second comment - do you have to use the fact that $y_1=ln(x)$ to come to that conclusion?

Comment: @Aaron, you do that for more complex differential equations; this one is really a first order for $y'.$

Comment: @abel But it's $y''$ - how is it first order?

Comment: The left side can be rewritten as $(xy')'$.  It's not hard to solve directly.

Comment: I did not use $y_1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael constants are not necessarily the solution. any linear combination of the first solution with a constant can be a solution too. **reduction of order** method is rather tedious but the questioner says in the comments that they are learning this method in class. Also reduction of order method shows that in the most general form $y_2(x)=c_1+c_2\ln x$ and you see that $y_2$ satisfies the differential equation so it can be a solution. It is the most general answer but depending on the initial values it can be converted to a constant as you said

Answer (score 1):

The given equation can be written as $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\,(xy')}{\mathrm{d}\,x}=0$$
Hence, you are looking for functions $y$ such that $$xy'=c_1$$ Where $c_1$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The way in which the problem is presented shows that we should use **reduction of order** method and solve the second solution with the help of the first one so we assume the second solution as:
$$y_2(x)=u(x)\ln(x)$$
$$y_2'(x)=u'(x)\ln(x)+\frac{u(x)}{x}$$
$$y_2''(x)=u''(x)\ln(x)+\frac{u'(x)}{x}+\frac{u'(x)x-u(x)}{x^2}$$
Substituting $y_2(x)$ in the main differential equation gives us:
$$u''(x)x\ln x+u'(x)(2+\ln x)=0$$
$$\frac{u''(x)}{u'(x)}=-\frac{2+\ln x}{x\ln x}=-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x\ln x}$$

**Hint: because you are dealing with indefinite integrals you should a constant $c_n$ when computing the integral** so:
Assume that $w=u''$
$$\frac{w'(x)}{w(x)}=-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x\ln x}$$
$$\ln w(x)=-\ln x-2\int x^{-1}{\ln x}^{-1}dx+c_1\qquad(c_1\,is\,constant)$$
To calculate $\int x^{-1}{\ln x}^{-1}dx$ we use the method **change of variables** so assume that $v=\ln x\Rightarrow dv=x^{-1}dx$ then $\int x^{-1}{\ln x}^{-1}dx=\int\frac{dv}{v}=\ln v=\ln(\ln x)$ and also there is no difference. We can wirite $c_1$ as $\ln c_1$ (both of them are arbitrary constants) so we will have:
$$\ln w(x)+\ln x=-2\ln(\ln x)+\ln c_1$$
$$\ln w(x)x=\ln(\ln x)^{-2}+\ln c_1$$
$$\ln w(x)x=\ln c_1(\ln x)^{-2}$$
$$xw(x)=c_1(\ln x)^{-2}$$
$$w(x)=c_1x^{-1}(\ln x)^{-2}$$
$$u'(x)=c_1x^{-1}(\ln x)^{-2}$$
**Hint: you are dealing with an indefinite integral and you should put a constant $c_2$ in your calculations**
$$u(x)=c_1(\int x^{-1}(\ln x)^{-2}dx+c_2$$
In order to calculate $\int x^{-1}(\ln x)^{-2}dx$ we use **change of variables** method so assume that $v=\ln x\Rightarrow dv=x^{-1}dx$ then $\int x^{-1}(\ln x)^{-2}dx=\int v^{-2}dv=-v^{-1}=-(\ln x)^{-1}$ so we will have:
$$u(x)=c_1(-(\ln x)^{-1}+c_2)=-c_1(\ln x)^{-1}+c_1c_2$$
There is nodifference. We can write $-c_1$ as $c_1$ and $c_1c_2$ as $c_2$ because all of them are arbitrary constants. so:
$$u(x)=c_1(\ln x)^{-1}+c_2$$
$$y_2(x)=u(x)y_1(x)=c_1+c_2\ln x$$
So in general form the second solution will be $y_2(x)=c_1+c_2\ln x$ and because we have no **initial values** we can't go further and specify the unique solution. If we had initial values, we could calculate $c_1$ and $c_2$ so both $y_2=1$ and $y_2=-1$ can be the answer. For example:

Initial values: $y_2(1)=y_2(2)=1\Rightarrow\,c_1=1\;c_2=0\Rightarrow \, y_2=1$
Initial values: $y_2(1)=y_2(2)=-1\Rightarrow\,c_1=-1\;c_2=0\Rightarrow \, y_2=-1$

**_________________________________________________________________________**

From the formula that you provided in the comments:
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int\frac{e^{-\int p(x)dx}}{y_1(x)^{2}}dx$$
we have $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'=0\Rightarrow p(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ so:
$$y_2(x)=\ln x\int\frac{e^{-\int\frac{dx}{x}}}{(\ln x)^2}dx=\ln x\int\frac{e^{\ln\frac{1}{x}}}{(ln x)^2}dx=-1$$
In fact when using the **reduction of order method** we say that if $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two special solutions of a homogenous second-order differential equation, any linear equation of them will be the general solution of the equation so the general solution will be:
$$y(x)=c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)=c_1(-1)+c_2(\ln x)$$
substituting $-c_1$ by $c_1$ (because they are both arbitrary constants) we can write:
$$y(x)=c_1+c_2(\ln x)$$
so there's no difference. either $-1$ or $1$ can be the second solution of the equation

Answer (score 1):

Put $ y^{'} =p \tag{1}$
$$ p + x \, p^{'} =0 $$
$$ xp = c_1$$
$$ \dfrac{dx}{x}=  \dfrac{d y}{c_1}   $$
$$ y/c_1 = log ( x/c_2) $$

Back substituting

$$ x p = x \dfrac{dy}{dx} = $$ const.

p is the negative constant, from (1).

Since p= any const., $ y_2 = x\cdot $ that constant, not a trivial solution.

Comment: there are various ways to solve the problem...but as the person says in the comments, they are learning the **reduction of order method** in class meaning that you should solve the second solution with the help of the first solution

Comment: yes, above done by back substitution of first solution.